# How to access error response from server using javascript / axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, vue.js, axios

I am using axios to post form data to Laravel.

Currently I am able to access the response if successful, however I'm having trouble accessing the error response. In dev tools, I can see my **network** > **response** has the following:

```
{"success":false,"data":{"message":"Token mismatch","refresh":true}}
```

I'm trying to access **refresh** to do a boolean comparison, so if its true the page will reload. How do I access this?

I've tried the following:

```
console.log(error.response);
console.log(error.response.data);
console.log(error.response.data.message);
console.log(error.data);
console.log(error);
```

Which log as the following respectively:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
undefined
undefined
Error: Request failed with status code 419
```

Comment: Parse the JSOn in order to work with the returned data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your server response contains `data` key. Axios also [uses this key](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) to in order to separate application data from HTTP protocol `status` and `headers`.

Assuming that you want to get `message` from the error response (that is "Token mismatch") try to access it using the following path:

`error.response.data.data.message`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

With your post request to avoid 419 error

Comment: Thanks, yes I already have a csrf field, but for the purpose of testing (removing cookies to bypass an age gate) I had to catch this error to force a page refresh / or do something else.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think you have found your answer. 

Answer (score 0):

As per the [https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors] documentation the error is available in the response.
use try catch instead

```
try {
    apiRes = axios.get('https://www.apponative.con');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error response:");
    console.error(err.response.data);    // ***
    console.error(err.response.status);  // ***
    console.error(err.response.headers); // ***
  } finally {
    console.log(apiRes);
  }
```